# How to add hash routing in Eleventy.js

Tags: hash, routes, electron-builder, eleventy

I want to add Hash-based routing to my Eleventy.js project so that it can be supported over the electron app. As I am getting blank screen and on further researching, I found out that it happens because of the use of Browser-based routing instead of Hash-based routing which is needed for electron-builder application to work in production mode.

So would require help in converting my eleventy application routing to hash based.

Comment: Eleventy generates static sites to is always browser-based routing. If you need client-side (hashed) routing then Eleventy is probably not the tool for using with electron-builder. Either use a different framework, or a different electron-packager

Comment: @LukeStorry got it, do you know of any other electron packager that doesn't use hashed routing??

Comment: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge might work

Comment: Sure will look into it